# How to connect to neo4j server in spring via rmi?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

How to connect to neo4j server in spring via rmi? I found http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-remote-graphdb. Is it component neo4j-remote-graphdb supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect with that library, which is also in http://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding

But you shouldn't use individual operations over the wire for higher performance operations, use Cypher instead (using RestGraphDatabase.query(query, params)) with Cypher **Parameters**.

Comment: but rest api slow than embed (with batch via rest 120 nodes was created 42360 ms but for embed 3540 ms)  and  spring neo4j doesn't support transaction for rest (I know I can write plugin for server but don't think this improve perfomance). Your shell works via rmi why you don't provide info about it oportunity for developers rmi faster than rest.